# Distance isn't being calculated in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager, distance

I am trying to calculate the distance travelled using CLLocationManager and display the distance inside of a label. Requesting to use location works but nothing shows in the label. I have tried simulating going on a drive inside the xCode simulator but no avail. I have a map displaying inside the app and that works, it tracks my location but thats all that works.

Heres my locationManager method:

```
func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {

    // Map

    theLabel.text = "\(locations[0])"
    myLocations.append(locations[0] as! CLLocation)

    let spanX = 0.007
    let spanY = 0.007
    let newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: theMap.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
    theMap.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)

    if (myLocations.count > 1){
        let sourceIndex = myLocations.count - 1
        let destinationIndex = myLocations.count - 2

        let c1 = myLocations[sourceIndex].coordinate
        let c2 = myLocations[destinationIndex].coordinate
        var a = [c1, c2]
        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
        theMap.add(polyline)
    }

    // Labels

    let latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]
    lat.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    long.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    horizAcc.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.horizontalAccuracy)
    altitude.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.altitude)
    vertAcc.text = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation.verticalAccuracy)

    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = latestLocation as! CLLocation
    }

    let distanceBetween = (latestLocation.distance(from: startLocation))

    distance.text = String(format: "%.2f", distanceBetween)

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I can supply more code if need be.

Comment: Can you please describe what exactly is not working? It's to broad to say "thats all that works"

Comment: I am calculating the distance and putting that into a label but the label never changes.

Comment: do `print(distanceBetween)` at last and tell the output

Comment: Through the use of print statements I've determined that the code never reaches the locationManager method, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: when you create your location manager, are you setting it's delegate?

Comment: @BJHStudios I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Try checking out location manager tutorials in iOS and you will know about that soon

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you do not have the delegate property set properly for your instance of [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager). You need to let it know which object contains your implementation of the [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate) methods, like the one you have listed.

So, assuming your view controller conforms to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and contains the method you posted and assuming you have given your view controller `CLLocationManager` property called "locationManager", you simply set it up like this:

```
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

You can place that in viewDidLoad: or wherever is appropriate for your needs and your didUpdateLocation delegate method should be called.